# Angular routing on apache is returning File not Found

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm using the PathLocationStrategy and deployed my angular14 application on apache. My angular application files are inside the folder "test", which is inside the folder "public_html".

so folder path looks like this: /var/www/game_sites/public_html/test

I have changed the .htaccess file that is inside the "public_html" and I'm still getting File Not found.

My base ref looks like so:

```
<base href="/teste/">
```

Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^/index.html
```

What am i doing wrong please? I'm guessing maybe the ReWrite rule is wrong?

I have tried updating the rewrite rule and changed to useHash but to no avail

Comment: So, presumably `/test/` is present in the URL? And the `index.html` file is located inside the `/test` subdirectory? `<base href="/teste/">` - presumably that should be `/test/`? But is the `base` element required to begin with?

Comment: Yes the index.html  file is located inside the /test subdirectory. Thanks for pointing out that typo. I used @MrWhite solution and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/index.html
> ```

You are missing a *space* between the `RewriteRule` arguments.

However, if all your files are in the `/test` subdirectory (including `index.html`) and `/test` is present in the URL then the `.htaccess` file should also be in the `/test` subdirectory, not the document root. It should then look like this:

```
# /test/.htaccess

DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Note there is no slash before `index.html` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

The relative substitution string is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. Likewise, the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is also relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

The first rule is just an optimisation and will work without it.

Comment: @CodeTzu You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (grey/green checkmark below the voting arrows) to help other readers. Thanks, much appreciated :)